# Why Html content is show in mail as it is send by Java Mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.setText(eMaster.getContent());
multipart.addBodyPart(mbp);
```

content is :`<html><b>Hello How are you doing....</b></html>`

it is shown in mail with html tags, why ?Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
mbp.setContent("<h1>Hello</h1>", "text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mbp.setText(eMaster.getContent(), "utf-8", "html");
```